# How to pass Picker value to parent component in React Native

Tags: react-native

I have a child Picker and it should pass selected value to it's parent. Components are in different .js files if it's important.
How can I pass the states of selected items?

parent

```
<RegionPicker regions={this.props.navigation.state.params.regionsJSON}/>
```

child:

```
export default class RegionPicker extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selected1: '1',
      selected2: '1'
        };
  }
  onValueChange1(value: string) {
    this.setState({selected1: value},
                  ()=>{ console.log('new',this.state.selected1)}
    );
  }
  onValueChange2(value: string) {
    this.setState({selected2: value},
                  ()=>{ console.log('new',this.state.selected2)}
    );
  }

    render() {
       return (
         <View>
             <Form>
               <Item inlineLabel>
                 <Label style={{fontSize:16}}>Region</Label>
                 <Picker
                   iosHeader="Select one"
                   mode="dropdown"
                   placeholder='...'
                   selectedValue={this.state.selected1}
                   onValueChange={this.onValueChange1.bind(this)}
                 >
                     {this.getRegions(this.props.regions).map((item, index) => {
                       return (<Picker.Item label={item} value={item} key={index}/>)
                     })}
                 </Picker>
               </Item>
               <Item inlineLabel last>
                 <Label style={{fontSize:16}}>Suburb</Label>
                 <Picker
                   iosHeader="Select one"
                   mode="dropdown"
                   placeholder='...'
                   selectedValue={this.state.selected2}
                   onValueChange={this.onValueChange2.bind(this)}
                 >
                 {this.getSuburbs(this.state.selected1).map((item, index) => {
                   return (<Picker.Item label={item} value={item} key={index}/>)
                 })}

               </Picker>
               </Item>
             </Form>

         </View>
       );
     }
   }
```

I would appreciate for any help and ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your parent, create a function that will *capture* your RegionPicker value. In this example, `myFunction`.

```
myFunction = (value) => {
  console.log(value);
}
```

Then pass down your function as a `prop`, like so:

```
<RegionPicker 
    regions={this.props.navigation.state.params.regionsJSON} 
    onChange={e => { this.myFunction(e) }}
/>
```

Inside of `RegionPicker` you can simply call your function within `onValueChange1()` and `onValueChange2()`.

```
this.props.onChange(value);
```

You should also `.bind()` your functions within the `constructor`. So inside of your `RegionPicker` you can add

```
this.onValueChange1 = this.onValueChange1.bind(this);
this.onValueChange2 = this.onValueChange2.bind(this);
```

And then just call
`this.onValueChange1` in your `Picker`'s `onValueChange` function.

Comment: THANK YOU so much! now passing to parent works perfect!!! so sorry I haven't much reputation to vote for your answer, but I'm SO grateful!

Answer (score 0):

As i thing you can do one thing you can get the value in the parent component

```
onValueChange={()=>{this.props.onValueChange1()}}
```

And in the component you call this function so you will get value

```
<RegionPicker onValueChange1={()=>{this.calculate()}}/>
```

calling the function in parent state will be

```
calculate (value: string){
 **Do you logic stuff here **

 }
```

May you get the value now